# Issues with enabling and disabling div visibility

Tags: javascript, css

I'm looking to create a similar window containing a form such as the one shown in the image below.

[image: Objective]

In my case when the log in link on the top navigation bar is clicked the screen containing the form is called.

My approach is to use a hidden div containing the form and its elements whilst calling functions to enable and disable the visibility of the div.

Currently I'm styling the div to be hidden as seen in the class log_in_form_div in public.css.

Below is my HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

   <title>Swim-mates - Sign Up or Log In</title>

   <!-- Generic CSS -->
   <link href="stylesheets/public.css" rel="stylesheet">

   <!-- Social networking log in button CSS -->
   <link href="stylesheets/auth-buttons.css" rel="stylesheet">

   <link href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/combo?2.6.0/build/reset-fonts-grids/reset-fonts-grids.css&2.6.0/build/base/base-min.css" rel="stylesheet" >

   <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
   <link href="stylesheets/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

   <!-- Custom CSS -->
   <link href="stylesheets/modern-business.css" rel="stylesheet">

   <!-- Custom Fonts -->
   <link href="font-awesome-4.1.0/stylesheets/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

   <!-- HTML5 Reset Stylesheet
   <link href="stylesheets/html5reset-1.6.1.css" rel="stylesheet"> -->

   <!-- Normalize CSS
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/normalize.css" />  -->    

</head>

<body>
    <nav id="topbar"> 
        <a id="logo_link" href="">ABCD corp</a>

        <ul>
            <li><a href='#' onclick="javascript:btnLogInForm();">LOG IN</a></li>
            <li><a href='#'>HOW IT WORKS</a></li>
            <li><a href='#'>FEATURES</a></li>
            <li><a href='#'>abcd.com</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>

    <!-- Welcome message -->
    <section class="welcome_message">Welcome message ... Welcome message ... Welcome message ... Welcome message ... Welcome message ... </section>

    <!-- Header Carousel -->
    <header id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">

        <!-- Indicators -->
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        </ol>

        <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="item active">
                <div class="fill" style="background-image:url('images/1900x1080imgtest1.jpg');"></div>

                <div class="carousel-caption">
                     Caption A
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="item">
                <div class="fill" style="background-image:url('images/1900x1080imgtest2.jpg');"></div>

                <div class="carousel-caption">
                     Caption B
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="item">
                <div class="fill" style="background-image:url('images/1900x1080imgtest3.jpg');"></div>

                <div class="carousel-caption">
                     Caption C
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>    
    </header>

    <!-- Page Content -->
    <section id="page_content" class="page_content_div">

        <div class="page_content_main_div">

            <div class="log_in_heading_div" >
                <p> Log in with: </p>
            </div>

            <div class="log_in_div">
                <a class="btn-auth btn-facebook large" href="#">Log in with <b>Facebook</b></a>
            </div>

            <div class="log_in_div">
                <a class="btn-auth btn-google large" href="#">Log in with <b>Google</b></a>
            </div>

            <div class="btn_log_in_with_email_div">
                <a class="btn-auth btn_log_in_with_email large" href="#">Log in with <b>Our details</b></a>
            </div>

            <hr class="hr"></hr>

            <form action="#" method="GET" class="sign_up_form">
                <div class="sign_up_heading_div">
                    <p>Sign up:</p>
                </div>                

                <div>
                    <input title="Enter first name" class="firstname" name="firstname" type="text" required placeholder="Enter first name">
                </div>

                <div>
                    <input title="Enter second name" class="secondname" name="secondname" type="text" required placeholder="Enter second name">
                </div>

                <div>
                    <input title="Enter an email" class="email" name="password" type="text" required placeholder="Enter email">
                </div>

                <div>
                    <input title="Enter a password" class="password" name="password" type="password" required placeholder="Enter password">
                </div>                

                <div>
                    <input title="Re-enter password" class="reenterpassword" name="reenterpassword" type="password" required placeholder="Re-enter password">
                </div>

                <div class="form_button_internal_div">
                    <button title="Type your second name" type="submit" class="btn_sign_up">Sign Up</button>
                </div>

                <div class="form_terms_of_service_internal_div">
                    <p class="terms_of_service">By signing up, I agree to the ABCD <a href='#' id="generic_link_decoration"><b>Terms of Service</b></a> and <a href='#' id="generic_link_decoration"><b>Privacy Policy</b></a>.</p>
                </div>                                
            </form>

        </div>
    </section>      

    <div class="log_in_form_div" id="log_in_form_div">
        <form class="log_in_form" action="#">
            <ol>
                <li class="group">
                    <label for="namefield">Username</label>
                    <input type="text" name="name" id="namefield" />
                </li>
                <li class="group">
                    <label for="passwordfield">Password</label>
                    <input type="text" name="password" id="passwordfield" />
                </li>
                <li class="group">
                    <div class="grouplabel">Sign up for</div>
                    <ol>
                        <li>
                            <input type="radio" name="membershiptype" value="beginner" id="beginnerbtn" />
                            <label for="beginnerbtn">Beginner</label>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <input type="radio" name="membershiptype" value="question" id="question" />
                            <label for="question">Pro</label>
                        </li>
                    </ol>
                </li>
            </ol>

            <button type="submit" class="btn_sign_up" id="btn_cancel_log_in_form" onclick="btnCancelLogInForm()">Cancel</button>

            <button type="submit" class="btn_sign_up" id="btn_send_log_in_form" onclick="btnCancelLogInForm()">Send</button>            
        </form>
    </div>

    <section>
        <footer class="footer_div"> 
            <ul>
                <li><a href='#'>ABOUT</a></li>
                <li><a href='#'>TERMS OF SERVICE</a></li>
                <li><a href='#'>FEATURES</a></li>
                <li><a href='#'>HELP</a></li>
            </ul>     
        </footer>    
    </section>

    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Script to Activate the Carousel i.e. directly related to carousel class name -->
    <script>
        $('.carousel').carousel( {
            interval: 3500 //changes the speed
        })

        function btnLogInForm() {
        document.getElementById("log_in_form_div").style.visibility="visible"; 
        }

        function btnCancelLogInForm() {
            document.getElementById("log_in_form_div").style.visibility = "hidden";
        }        
    </script>     

</body>

</html>
```

Below is my CSS code:

```
enter code here      padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
/* Insert a gap after every <ul> element */
.footer_div ul:after {
    content:" ";
    display: block;
    font-size: 0;
    height: 0;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
}

/* ul li a */
.footer_div ul li a {
    font-family:'Trebuchet MS', Tahoma, Sans-serif;
    color: #F5F5F5;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    padding: 15px 15px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 19px;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-transition: color .25s;
    -moz-transition: color .25s;
    -ms-transition: color .25s;
    -o-transition: color .25s;
    transition: color .25s;
}

/* ul li a:hover */
.footer_div ul li a:hover {
    color: #000000;
}

/* Bullet point after the menu name 
.footer_div ul li a:after {
    content:"";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    right: -3px;
    top: 19px;
    height: 6px;
    width: 6px;
    background: #F5F5F5;
    opacity: .5;
} */

/* Insert content before every <a> element's content */
.footer_div ul li a:before {
    content:"";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 3px;
    width: 0;
    background: #00FF00;
    -webkit-transition: width .25s;
    -moz-transition: width .25s;
    -ms-transition: width .25s;
    -o-transition: width .25s;
    transition: width .25s;
}

/* */
.footer_div ul li.last > a:after,.footer_div ul li:last-child > a:after {
    display: none;
}

/* */
.footer_div ul li.active a {
    color: #999999;
}

/* */
.footer_div ul li.active a:before {
    width: 100%;
}

/* */
.footer_div.align-right li.last > a:after,.footer_div.align-right li:last-child > a:after {
    display: block;
}

/* */
.footer_div.align-right li:first-child a:after {
    display: none;
}
```

My questions are:

1. Is the approach I'm undertaking the best?
2. I seem to be making an error in the javascript bit of my code where    by I'm attempting to enable and disable the div?

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you use jquery to hide/show your content?

Comment: Why re-invent the wheel? use lightbox

Comment: Try `Bootstrap's` modals. They provide readily available event handling as well as popups which will serve your purpose. Go here: www.getbootstrap.com

Comment: @Marcus: Bootstrap is *horrible* to use. Plus there's *far* better plugins that it for popups!

Comment: @jbutler483: Well, we may disagree on that. But bootstrap isn't for popups only; it gives you the responsiveness! I've worked on alot of BS sites n all of em seem pretty with BS's integration and not horrible! Plus, he's already using it. So why not use modals!

Comment: @Marcus: I know it's not 'just for popups' - I've used it before (a long time ago now), and due to it's stupid css classes, I dumped it and started actually *learning* css myself. Since then, responsive sites come as a doddle! But using bootstrap doesn't **teach** you css, which I feel is a lot more important than 'using' css.

Comment: There has come a lot of difference in that 'long time', my friend. Companies are now hiring by asking questions specific to latest version of BS. I'm sure you must have had better experience than mine; I'm not an expert after all. But anyways, you can't say one can't learn to code css while using BS. I've learned so much while using it. Infact, I've learned how to exploit it's classes as per my comfort! Anyways, let's just answer the guy's question here.

Comment: @Marcus: Thanks for the comments .. If anything from both your comments I at least know the basic pros and cons of using bootstrap. I will look at bootstrap modals as I didn't know a great deal about it. My first reaction was to build the popup window from scratch using CSS.

Comment: @jbutler483: The above message also applies to your much appreciated responses.

Answer (score 0):

For your nav menu, you can use jquery like this. You just need to change nav tag with this

```
<nav id="topbar"> 
        <a id="logo_link" href="">ABCD corp</a>

        <ul>
            <li><a href='#' id="login">LOG IN</a></li>
            <li><a href='#'>HOW IT WORKS</a></li>
            <li><a href='#'>FEATURES</a></li>
            <li><a href='#'>abcd.com</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

in your script tag just add this.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#login').click(function(){
     $('#log_in_form_div').show();
   });
   $('#btn_cancel_log_in_form').click(function(){
    $('#log_in_form_div').hide();
   });
   $('.carousel').carousel( {
            interval: 3500 //changes the speed
        });
)};




    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use "display" CSS property to completely hide and show elements from DOM.

```
function btnLogInForm() {
        document.getElementById("log_in_form_div").style.display="block"; 
        }

function btnCancelLogInForm() {
                document.getElementById("log_in_form_div").style.display="none";
            }
```

You can make life easier by using [Bootstrap Modal](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals) or jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

your  using bootstrap framework in your code .
 I think its better to use bootstrap modal for the form displays.
 Bootstrap modal allows you to display modal popups easily and efficiently

[bootstrap modal](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals)

Answer (score 0):

In the fiddle it works when I change it to display: http://jsfiddle.net/e2fhr3ju/1/

Difference between visibility and display: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_display_visibility.asp

CSS:

```
#log_in_form_div {
    display:none;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    border:1px solid black;
}
```

Javascript:

```
function btnLogInForm() {
    document.getElementById("log_in_form_div").style.display = "block";
}

function btnCancelLogInForm() {
    document.getElementById("log_in_form_div").style.display = "none";
}
```